# Android ImageView set to local URL not working?

Tags: java, android, image, url

So I am new to Android, but I do not understand why this does not work (and how to get it to work):

```
ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_display);
Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
i.setImageURI(uri)
```

I did a Toast and have made sure that uri.toString() returns a url like `content://...`
I am also sure that `i` is a valid reference, because I am successfully able to set it to local images that are part of the `.apk`.

So why would this not work, and how can I get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: In regards to what? I found nothing in the log pertaining to this problem. The `ViewGroup` loads and throws no errors, but no image displays.

Comment: Are you able to successfully access the image from the content provider through any other means?

Comment: How so? I have the valid URI, but I don't know how else to access the image.

Comment: What kind of URI is it? Is it coming from MediaStore.Images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't HAVE to have it be an Uri you could do something like this instead.

```
String fullpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pathtoyourfile"

        // take the path create a bitmap and populate the ImageView with it.
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullpath);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Well how would I translate the URI to work that way? Sometimes the data that I am accessing is on internal storage, so I am not sure that that would work.

Comment: URI.parse maybe. You just need a text path to your file. URI provides a few ways to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it yourself and then passing it in:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

if (bitmap != null) {
    i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Alright, I am very confused. So I checked `bitmap`, it was not null as I set a Toast in the case that it was, but at the same time no image was displayed! Could the URI from `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` be inaccurate?